# Installing caffe on Yosemite Boost Error

Tags: c++, boost, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on Yosemite and I am getting the following error:

`make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_clang.hpp', needed by '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o'.  Stop.`

As suggested by this blogpost [compiling caffe on Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745837/compiling-caffe-on-yosemite) I downgraded the Boost to v1.57.

Any suggestions on how to move forward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
make clean
make all
```